# Is it possible to have a configurable attribute which is type text

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute

Is it possible to have a configurable attribute which is `type text instead of drop down or multiple select` ?

I want to have a configurable product but the values are pretty much endless so rather than entering them all as dropdown options and then selecting 1 value out of that list I want to see if its possible to have an attribute which can be used to create a configurable product which is type text

Comment: Can you please explain more what is purpose of doing so ?

Comment: I have updated the question, does this help?

Comment: if it will be text field then how child product of configurable product will be selected for adding them to cart? how can we decide which child product user need to purchase?

Comment: You should use custom options to do this

Answer (score 2):

No , It is not possible.
Configurable attribute must be of Type Drop down and the scope must be set to Global.
What type of products you are using that has the endless options.